Babylonian pronunciation for Talmud Bavli?
Did certain traits of the Babylonian Masoretic pronunciation, also apply to the aramaic of the Talmud Bavli?
For example, in Tanakh, according to the most common tradition, ו is pronounced [v], like as בֿ.
However, the Babylonian Masoretes had ו as [w], preserving the even more ancient pronunciation.
The Talmud Bavli was, obviously, written in Bavel. Are there any grounds to believe that this ו was originally pronounced in the Gemara as W, instead of V?
Does this also apply to other aspects of the Babylonian pronunciation of Tanakh (e.g. Segol-Patach merger, some words with a silent initial Shva, ר being an “Italian” trill, etc.)?
Edit: My focus is on the first and last paragraphs. If the answer would be “yes” in most cases except regarding the pronunciation of ו, please say so. I only used ו as an example, and I realize there are many other examples I could have used.

Probably whoever read it read it however they usually spoke, no matter where or when they lived.

@DoubleAA I agree. I am curious, however, as to what the authors’ and redactors’ pronunciations were.

Why do you think that Tiberian Jews pronounced vav as v and not w?

@Kazibácsi There are multiple instances of Tiberian Masoretic treatises contrasting ו with “Babylonian ו”, and some even some explicitly compare it to ב. Karate transcriptions into Arabic from around that time—initially based on the Tiberian reading tradition—used the same character for ו and ב. There’s even one case of ו being written with the Arabic character for F, which could only work if ו was pronounced as ב then devoiced to פ.

Then add this relevant information in your post!

@Kazibácsi As stated at the end of my post, I just used ו as an example. What I really want to know is if certain traits of the Babylonian Masoretic pronunciation might reflect the how the Babylonian Judeo-Aramaic of the Talmud was pronounced during its development and/or publication. Those traits may or may not include the pronunciation of ו.

Then your question is trivial. People usually use the same sound set to pronounce both their native language and foreign languages. Therefore Americans will use a very characteristic rhotic r sound for the Hebrew ר, the French will make it guttural and I say it as a trill. Same story with the Ashkenazi s for ת. It's very difficult to deviate from this. Therefore it's clear that the Babylonians used the same sounds for reading the Tanakh and teaching the Talmud. (And I'm also sure that it wasn't uniform due to dialects. See also Megillah 24b.)

@Kazibácsi Not necessarily. Firstly, the Masoretic era didn’t overlap the Talmudic era, but rather came after it; and secondly, Biblical Hebrew is not the same as Babylonian Judeo-Aramaic. An identical written consonantal system and just-barely-comparable vocabulary and grammar does not necessarily correspond to a similar or identical phonological or phonetic structure—although it might. That’s what I’m trying to discover.

I knew a family of Iraqi Jews. They said thaw, dhalet, waw, distinguished quf and caf, etc.

There are still surviving dialects of Aramaic in Iraq. One example is Syriac, and here it is with a waw
https://youtu.be/lOD1JC5JLDw?si=CT2xfaLzS7v5ZVvv
This doesn't prove what the Bavli sounded like. But Waw in Semitic languages seems to be a letter that's part consonant and part vowel, same as yod. Aramaic, Arabic, and other semitic languages usually spoke it as Waw, as making it a Vav shifts it more to being a consonant than a vowel. Most Iraqi Jews I've met also pronounce it as Waw for their Hebrew. Iraqis even have their own Aleph bet song that they teach to their kids and sing for Simhat Torah. The song is called Aleph Bet Gimmel Dalet Heh Waw: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0rBDx1TeniU

Rabbi Saadia Gaon in commentary to sefer Yetzirah seems to be acknoledging that vav is w, by comparing sounds of classical arabic and Hebrew.
